# Visual Studio - Resource (CSS/JS/Images) sharing between web projects

Tags: visual-studio, deployment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handling common JavaScript files in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107464/handling-common-javascript-files-in-visual-studio-2010)

I'm looking to share a common pool of web resources (css/js/images) across multiple web projects. What I'm hoping to do, is create one project file for the resources, e.g.: **Common.WebResources**, and include it in the Visual Studio solutions for **Site1** & **Site2**.

The part I'm looking to solve is setting it up to work with the **VS Development Server** (the one that gets fired up on *F5*), and any outer deployment concerns.

So we're hoping to wind up with the following projects mapped to the following web directories:

- Site1.Web - **/**
- Common.WebResources - **/resources**

In IIS, it would just be a virtual directory. So far with VS Development Server, I've only been able to:

- Get them to deploy on different ports (not a lot of use)
- Add a post-build event to copy the contents of /resources into Site1.Web

My questions are:

- **What other options are there?**
- **Which do you feel to be the most appropriate, usable & maintainable?**

(The reason I'd like the resources in a single, separate project is to avoid having to constantly merge a master resources location into each of the consuming sites, and merging back from each fix we make.)

Comment: Which version control tool are you using? Some of them have features that may help you do what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: We are using MS Team Foundation Server for source control.

As mentioned in Chris's reply, keeping the resources in a single, source controlled directory is a key requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a second Web.Resources project for the second site, but link the files from the first resource.  I know this means that you have an extra project, but in a way it's good because you have abstract the resources, but still maintained a certain level of separation.

To link files go  ....  Add--> Existing Item --> Select file(s) --> Beside "Add" there is a down arrow --> Click "Add As Link".

Hope this helps.

Comment: what you suggested doesnt work for content files like javascript/css/ or images

Comment: Yep, sadly the linked files aren't actually copied into the directories, so when running the app, they don't exist on the server :(

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is one place where VS seems to fall down - I've been struggling with a similar problem.

One option you can try is to keep your resources in a separate, source controlled directory, and have a pre-build step that makes sure that there's a current copy in a directory visible, but not part of, the solution.

There are lots of drawbacks to this - you'll probably get warnings about missing css classes, and I'm not sure if javascript intellisense will be enabled, so if you do find a resolution, make sure you update your question!