# Visual Studio 2010 and linked resources

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, embedded-resource

I have many javascript libraries shared between many projects. They are located in a shared folder, I point to them adding in my project as Link (Add Existing Item > Add as Link).

The problem is that those files are not copied in my local solution, so when I run the website they are missing.

I made something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107464/handling-common-javascript-files-in-visual-studio-2010) but does not to much sense to me having those files in my bin folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After adding the linked files, look at their properties.
 There should be a property 'copy to output directory'. Just set this to 'always' or 'only if newer' and it copies the files.